# Can't make two div's occupy half the space inside its container with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, styling

I'm trying to center two divs inside its container with flexbox and it should make it automatically. I've tried using `flex: 1` and isn't working. This is my structure.

```css
#opacScreen {
  display: block;
  z-index: 35;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

#searchbarWindow {
  z-index: 40;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#divsearchbar {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1
}

#displaysearch {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<div id="opacScreen">
  <div id="searchbarWindow">
    <div id="divsearchbar">
      <label for=""><svg id="imageLens"></svg></label>
      <input id="searchbar" type="" placeholder="Search Device">
    </div>
    <div id="displaysearch">
      <p>No recent searches</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The results so far. I would want the red and green div to occupy 50% of its parent and the red one is eating almost all the space.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you also show us your html?

Comment: just make some research on google....[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container)

Comment: can you provide the image of the exact output how you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. `display: flex` way

For the `display: flex` with `flex-direction: column`, you are doing everything right except the flex container will need a fixed `height`. Simply add a `height: 500px` to `#searchbarWindow` you are good to go.

### 2. `display: grid` way

In case you don't have a fixed height for the container, you might want to use `display: grid` instead.

```
#searchbarWindow {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/blackcityhenry/pen/LYmPrNK) of the `display: grid` way.